# how to get first element of every sublist of a list (django template)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

There is a list in view.py

```
alist = [['Australian', 10], ['Canadian', 20], ['German', 6]]
context = {
  'alist':alist
}
```

In the HTML, How can I display the first element of each sublist only.
like

```
<a>Australian</a>
<a>Candian</a>
<a>German</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for element in alist %}
    <a>{{ element[0] }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just a simple typo. Fixed it.